# Can immigration authorities make cross checks between multiple passports of the same (German) person?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, turkey, german-citizens

I have the following specific case but it would be nice to have a general answer if one does exist:

A fellow German traveler just spent 3 months in Turkey on his passport. He just then left to Bulgaria, the rule is to wait three months before he could enter for another three months. But Germans can enter Turkey with just their ID card or if they have, a second passport, so he is going to try using his ID when going back to Turkey tomorrow.

Is there a way for the Turkish border authorities to link the two different Passports/IDs and see that he is not really allowed to enter?

I guess the name and date of birth is the same on both, but that is not unique enough.

I am sure German authorities could link the two papers but can it be done by foreign countries?

Comment: Just to check - are you aware that the 3 month restriction is normally on a person, not on a set of credentials? So if your friend was to re-enter inside the 3 months using different credentials, even if he was let in, he's still likely to be entering illegally (depending exactly on what Turkish law says)

Comment: It is illegal to enter Turkey like this, but i know people doing that and they haven't had any problem. But it does not mean that your friend will not be  in trouble if something unexpected arises. Not sure if this is an answer or a comment.

Comment: No idea about actual practice in Turkey but too many false positive is not necessarily a reason for them not to do anything (cf. no-fly lists and the like). Generally speaking, whether some country give its immigration authorities the right to do X or Y or choose to have reasonable rules in place is entirely up to them (with the caveat that this might also be covered by some international treaty). We (Germany and other EU countries…) certainly subject foreigners to a lot of arbitrary restrictions and catch-22 situations.

Answer (score 6):

The tupple full name, date of birth, and country (which is present in both the passport and the id card) is usually unique to an individual <sup>1</sup>.

If the border authority stores this data in a database along with entry date, they will notice the same person attempting to enter before the allowed time, even though the passport number and the id card number are totally different.

They don't **need** access to the foreign issuing authority (Bewohneramt in this case) to do this, just to keep and check their **own** records.

Whether specifically Turkey actually does this, and also actively enforces it, is another question which I can't answer.

<sup>1</sup> In the cases it isn't, people can often experience problems when dealing with bureaucracy.

Comment: Also specifically, modern German Passports and id cards are biometric - If they store and check this data, the authorities would have no problems catching people re-entering too soon.

Comment: Since biometrics are retaken for each passport, matching them is actually not straightforward.  However, they do make it trivial to confirm that the two passports with the same name, birth date etc belong to the same person

Answer (score 3):

Of course they can. And they have the right to do it.

Will they likely do it? That's is another question.

Comment: Paranoia mode: Now, after reading your question on The Internetz they will surely do...

Comment: I agree that they have the right to do so, but how are they technically able to do this? They may have a list with my name, birthday and passport number. But just matching name and birthday would bring back too many false positives.

Comment: Many is an overstatement. What are the chances that two different people with the same name, same birth date and same birth place enter the same country in a short amount of time?